# How to select results when using 2 paired arrays as inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

[Order_Header] & [Order_Item]

[Order_Header] has fields: bus_day_id, check_no, order_hdr_id 
[Order_Item] has fields: menu_item_id, tax_amt, order_hdr_id

I need the tax_amt for a given menu_item_id on a check_no

I can do a single query with the following command:

```
int @a
int @b
int @c

Select menu_item_id, tax_amt_incl_sales, check_no 
FROM [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Item]

WHERE order_hdr_id = (SELECT [order_hdr_id]
FROM [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Header]
WHERE check_no = @a
AND bus_day_id = @b)
AND menu_item_id = @c
```

What I'd like to do is input a table of values for @a, @b & @c similar to the following:

```
bus_day check_no    menu_item_id
1       1000        50
2       1001        51
3       1002        52
4       1003        53
4       1003        54
```

This will be called from c# either via a direct select statement, or a stored procedure.

Thanks for any help

Edit:

This potentially works, but im still convinced there is a better way of doing it:

```
Select menu_item_id, tax_amt_incl_sales, [Order_Header].check_no
FROM [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Item]
INNER JOIN [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Header]
ON [Order_Header].[order_hdr_id] = [Order_Item].[order_hdr_id]
WHERE [Order_Header].order_hdr_id IN
((SELECT [order_hdr_id]   FROM [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Header]  where check_no = 20412  AND bus_day_id = 179),
 (SELECT [order_hdr_id]   FROM [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Header]  where check_no = 20410  AND bus_day_id = 179),
 (SELECT [order_hdr_id]   FROM [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Header]  where check_no = 20409  AND bus_day_id = 179))
```

Comment: Are there going to be multiple order_hdr_ids for given check_no and bus_day_id??

Comment: is there a one - to - one relation between the order_header table and order_item table?

Comment: bus_day_id and check_no is 1:1. order_hdr_id can be many:1 for check_no which is why it needs the bus_day_id as a 2nd clause.

Comment: each order_hdr_id in order_header will corespond to the same order_hdr_id  in order_item, but there will be multiple rows with that id

Comment: re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the non-standard SQL used

Comment: Plenty of examples on how to use a table valued parameter in sql server, even in the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Using Joins is always preferred if your R-DBMS supports them.
There won't be any difference in performance but semantic wise you are separating the relationships (JOINS) form the filters (WHERE).

Your second solution is almost OK but you don't need the sub queries:

```
SELECT 
      menu_item_id, tax_amt_incl_sales, [Order_Header].check_no
FROM 
      [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Item]
INNER JOIN 
      [it_trn].[dbo].[Order_Header]
ON 
      [Order_Header].[order_hdr_id] = [Order_Item].[order_hdr_id]
WHERE 
      bus_day_id = 179 AND 
      [Order_Header].check_no IN (20412, 20410, 20409)
```

You should also prefix all the attributes in the SELECT clause in order to prevent future conflicts (ie: adding a tax_amt_incl_sales attribute to the other table in the future)

---- UPDATE ---- WHERE CLAUSE CAN NOT USE 'IN' syntax

```
WHERE 
      (bus_day_id = 179 AND [Order_Header].check_no = 20412) OR
      (bus_day_id = 179 AND [Order_Header].check_no = 20410) OR
      (bus_day_id = 179 AND [Order_Header].check_no = 20409)
```

Comment: That's very close to what I need, but the bus_day_id won't always be the same for each check_no. I can't use and IN statement for both bus_day_id and check_no because that will pull erroneous results. It just needs to be the 1st bus_day_id with 1st check no, 2nd with 2nd, 3rd with 3rd etc...